# Error showing for update include path and cannot open source file studio.h, stdlib.h , iostream i.e. all header file

Tags: error-handling, path, header-files

Error showing for update include path and cannot open source file studio.h, stdlib.h , iostream i.e. all header file[enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYia.jpg[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYia.jpg%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnNnu.jpg))

I tried changing different path compiler in intelisence, I tried to find solutions in chatgpt. Nothing work. I uninstalled all vs code and mingw file and reinstall it still same problem happening.